# Pronunciation of -ar in Madagascar

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, ipa

In the movie by the same name, the characters pronounce *Madagascar*, /mædəɡæsk**ɑ**ɹ/. However, dictionaries only list the pronunciation /mædəɡæsk**ə**ɹ/. Just as peculiarly, many pronounce *templar* as /tɛmpl**ɑ**ɹ/, while dictionaries only list /tɛmpl**ə**ɹ/.

Is this an American convention, a mispronunciation by people trying to pronounce the words as they're spelled, or something else?

Comment: I'm no specialist but I'd say that both versions are correct, maybe it's a regional difference. Or the pronunciation with a schwa is what it should sound like in General American. I'm interested whether someone else can give an explanation.

Comment: In unstressed syllables, vowels often get reduced. So if you consider *templar* to have a "true" vowel of /ɑ/ in the second syllable, saying /tɛmpləɹ/ is the standard way to reduce it, which most people would use when speaking fast. And if you hear somebody saying /tɛmpləɹ/ and look at the spelling, you might infer that the real vowel is /ɑ/. [Walker's pronouncing dictionary](https://archive.org/stream/walkerspronounc00unkngoog#page/n384/mode/2up) from 1828 says the vowel is the same as *far*, so I assume that both pronunciations have been around for the last couple centuries.

Comment: I (AmE) have always pronounced the last syllable as “car” just like the vehicle and have never heard anyone pronounce it with a schwa.

Comment: My unsupported suspicion is that Madagascar being a country that barely ever reaches even the fringe of American consciousness, people pronounce it as they *think* it would sound. Almost every common word ending in *-car* is a compound of *car* or *scar*, thus /kɑr/ is more natural, and in particular, the temptation is irresistible to rhyme a word ending in *-ascar* with *NASCAR*, hence -/'æs kɑr/.

Comment: @Jim, I've never heard any American pronounce it with a schwa either. It sounds English to me.

Comment: @Peter Shor, thank you for the insight. That eliminates one as an irregularity.

Comment: Up until Disney's Madagascar movie, everybody in the Northeast that I know pronounced it "Mad-a-gask-er".
after the Disney movie everyone started pronouncing it ending with "car", and it seems to have stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it's an American convention.

---

The link to the 1828, American dictionary entry for *Templar* that *@Peter Shor* provided lists, in another transcription system, /tɛmplɑɹ/. I was also able to find one online American dictionary, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/madagascar), that does list the /mædəɡæskɑɹ/ pronunciation of *Madagascar* but no English dictionary that does so. The Oxford English Dictionaries and the Cambridge English Dictionary, for example, list only the schwa pronunciations for *Madagascar* and *Templar*.

This offers a few possible conclusions. As *@choster* pointed out, many words that end in -(s)car are pronounced /(s)kɑɹ/, so it could be the natural tendency to pronounce other words this way. *@Peter Shor* says that this is the standard way to reduce the vowel in unstressed syllables, so it could be reduced to the schwa pronunciation for speakers that normally have /ɑ/, depending on speed. Finally, *@Benjamin Harman* says it's most common for British speakers to reduce a final vowel of this type to /ɐ-ɜ/ (if I'm reading correctly).

Answer (score 3):

In American English, we hear the *-car* that ends the name Madagascar pronounced just like the word "car" meaning a motor vehicle.  The American pronunciation is clearly said the same as in if an American were to say, "I was mad a gas car wasn't available."

In British dialects, however, the A is de-emphasized and so less tall, being most commonly pronounced like the *-car* at the end of the name Oscar, which tends to be slightly taller at the back of the throat than words that end in *-er* but not much taller, certainly not as tall as the word *car*.